# Angular 10 --proxy.conf not redirecting requests to target

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, proxy

either I missed something or the `--proxy-configuration` does not work properly anymore.
I am trying to consume `http://localhost:56209/api/authenticate/login` but it does not seem to work.
All requests with Postman work perfectly fine.

The Debug log revealed that the requests are in fact being redirected, but the Chrome console tells me otherwise.

```
10% building 3/3 modules 0 active [HPM] Proxy created: /api  ->  http://localhost:56209/
[HPM] Subscribed to http-proxy events:  [ 'error', 'close' ]

chunk {main} main.js, main.js.map (main) 610 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {polyfills} polyfills.js, polyfills.js.map (polyfills) 141 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {runtime} runtime.js, runtime.js.map (runtime) 6.15 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {styles} styles.js, styles.js.map (styles) 566 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {vendor} vendor.js, vendor.js.map (vendor) 4.49 MB [initial] [rendered]
Date: 2020-10-14T22:31:04.463Z - Hash: 5dd334fd8f37fa963b18 - Time: 11697ms
** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **
: Compiled successfully.
[HPM] POST /api/authenticate/login -> http://localhost:56209/
```

[Chrome console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U9JKw.png)

```
Request URL: http://localhost:4200/api/authenticate/login
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 400 Bad Request
Remote Address: 127.0.0.1:4200
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
```

I have removed `node_modules` cleared the cache even created a new project which tries to consume a public API - still the same results.

Below some crucial information for this behavior

```js
const headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type','application/json');
    const jsonifiedLoginRequest = JSON.stringify(loginRequest);
    this.http.post<LoginResponse>("/api/authenticate/login", jsonifiedLoginRequest, {headers: headers}).subscribe(x => {
      console.log(x);
    });
```

```
ng --version
Angular CLI: 10.1.4
Node: 12.18.4
OS: win32 x64

Angular: 10.1.4
... animations, cli, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, router
Ivy Workspace: Yes

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1001.4
@angular-devkit/build-angular   0.1001.4
@angular-devkit/core            10.1.4
@angular-devkit/schematics      10.1.4
@angular/cdk                    10.2.4
@angular/flex-layout            10.0.0-beta.32
@angular/material               10.2.3
@schematics/angular             10.1.4
@schematics/update              0.1001.4
rxjs                            6.6.3
typescript                      4.0.3
```

```json
src/proxy.conf.json

{
  "/api": {
    "target": "http://localhost:56209/",
    "logLevel":"debug",
    "secure":false
  }
}
```

Obviously I have tried `/api/*` as well, but to no avail.

```json
angular.json (only the serve part)

  "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "SageFrontend:build",
            "proxyConfig": "src/proxy.conf.json"
          }
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Have you also tried `/api/*`?

Comment: Yes - to no avail

Answer (score 0):

Weirdly, the reason why this did not work is because the payload sent in the POST looked like this

```json
{ "UserName" : "", "Password" : "" }
```

If I send a request with proper values like

```json
{ "UserName" : "test", "Password" : "somePassword!1111!" }

The proxy manages to divert the call properly. 

I have no idea why this is happening.
```

EDIT:
The Error message in the chrome console tricked me into believing that the error is actually coming from the angular webserver. If you navigate further down in the error tree, you see the actual response from the service wrapped in a error from the angular server.